# Microsoft Teams Graph API List members

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

When using the microsoft teams graph api to get list of members in a team, I'm also getting the owner names as part of the list. Is there any easy way to get just the members? Currently I'm using a complicated method of making two graph calls, one for owners and another for members and then manually comparing and eliminating owners from the member list.

Comment: Could you please try using query parameters to filter the response based on a condition.

Comment: I tried looking for any differences in the objects returned for member vs owner, but couldn't find anything differentiating the owner, so query parameters won't help

Comment: Currently, owners are also considered as members inside a team. You could get intersection with [List Owners](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-owners?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to get all members. Currently, we do not have any plans to change this behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a Bot as part of your project, then instead of using the Graph you can use the latest release of the Bot Framework to get the relevant people. See the [V4.9 release note](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/releases/tag/4.9.0) of the bot framework, which state:

> The TeamsChannelAccount object has been updated to include userRole (one of owner, member, or guest) and tenantId (for the user's tenantId).

Comment: Thanks. This would have been an ideal solution for me but, unfortunately I'm not using any bots in my code right now.